# Generate 2d world with vectors

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I try to get started with a 2d map generator with vectors. Now I have some questions how should I go for it.

```
public float[] gen() {
    float[] vec = new float[100];
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    float a = 20,
          b = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i += 2) {
        vec[i] = MathUtils.random(x, x + a);
        vec[i+1] = MathUtils.random(y - b, y + b);
        x = vec[i];
        y = vec[i+1];
    }
    return vec;
}
```

1. Would this be a good way to get verctors from? var a, b could be changed for smooth land / hills.
2. I thought about a neverending map. But how could I only render the part of the player sees. I will work with box2d.
3. Generated world parts should be saved to a file. Should I save them as chunks like in Minecraft done? And what file fromat is reccoment (json)?

I just liked to get a little perpective to look forwart.

Comment: I suggest you investigate some well-known terrain generation algorithms, and see how they accomplish things, such as the diamond-square algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm That will give you perspective on how to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for 2nd Q.

**You have to have a** [**Camera**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)

```
if(x >=camera.project(new Vector3(camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth - 25, 0, 0)).x) && x <= camera.project(new Vector3(camera.viewportWidth + camera.position.x + 25, 0, 0)).x)
```

and y the same or less laggy than this(every frame there is created new 
Vector3 object, so...)
Good luck!